# Line break in title on aggregated page of Hugo site

Tags: html, css, r, hugo, blogdown

The question might be a little confusing. But I'm using the amazing `blogdown` package to try out some fun blogging. While I not yet dived really deep into Hugo and their variables, I thought there must be a simple way to make a blog-post with a long title that will be broken up into multiple lines on an index-page. I just don't know where to start looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily modify hugo themes. To customize a theme go to **themes/theme-name/layouts/** You will find here all the layouts and templates that make up the theme of your site.